# The CA2104 warning: Is there any way to mark a class as `Immutable` to suppress it?

Tags: c#, immutability, code-analysis

Consider the following code, which provokes [`CA2104: Do not declare read only mutable reference types.`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28CA2104%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework)

```
public class Test
{
    // This provokes CA2104: "Do not declare read only mutable reference types".
    protected readonly ImmutableClass ImmutableMember;
}

public class ImmutableClass
{
}
```

Does anyone know of a way to mark a class as immutable in a way that would suppress warning CA2104?

I tried decorating `MutableClass` with [`[ImmutableObject(true)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.immutableobjectattribute.aspx) with no hope of success (since that attribute is pretty clearly for the Form Editor to use), and sure enough it doesn't work.

I assume that Code Analysis is using a list of known immutable types when determining whether to emit CA2104, so we can't use the same approach.

I guess that even if you *could* mark a class as immutable, there'd be no way for the compiler to actually check if it was true, but at least it could be a useful indicator.

Anyway, are there any attributes I'm overlooking? If not, suppression will have to do.

It seems that there is no alternative way to do this *at the moment*.

I did find [an interesting blog from Joe Duffy (author of "Concurrent Programming On Windows") about this kind of thing](http://joeduffyblog.com/2007/11/11/immutable-types-for-c/).

He starts off with *"Imagine we had an ImmutableAttribute."*... :)

It's quite interesting - he went to the trouble of writing some new FxCop rules to do some analysis of types attributed as immutable.

Comment: Why mark it as `readonly`?

Comment: @Davin Tryon: Because the property must be initialised in construction and thereafter never changed, just like `readonly` is always used. Surely the same reason as you'd mark *anything* readonly?

Comment: Thought so, you just didn't mention.  It looks like a one-off suppression to me.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it. I'm not overly fussed, I just wish there was a proper attribute to express my intent. There's a `[Pure]` attribute for "pure" functions (for Code Contracts); you'd think Microsoft would have introduced something for `Immutable`. Maybe I should go and suggest it...

Comment: @MatthewWatson I completely agree with you that there should be an `ImmutableAttribute` that is just used to indicate that your class is supposed to be immutable (just like `[Pure]` for pure methods). You have raised a valid point in this question, and [Hans Passant's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15742160/146622) is to _just suppress it_, which is obviously not a solution.

Comment: Complain to Microsoft, this is not the right place.

Comment: @Hans: Of course, your comment may not have been addressed to me, but if it was: I wasn't complaining, in fact I said I wasn't overly fussed! :) I was merely asking if there was any alternative to suppressing it.

Comment: @MatthewWatson It was addressed to me.

Comment: Have you tried `protected ImmutableClass ImmutableMember { get; private set;}` then allowed initialization of `ImmutableMember` only through a base constructor?

Comment: @Peter Ritchie: Aye, that would work, but unfortunately it means that you can still change its value in the base class (which `readonly` would prevent). I like `readonly` for my immutable classes. :)

Comment: It's not a one-off suppression when you're implementing the strong typed enum pattern... ugh.

Comment: I have used this pattern in the past.  I've decided that it sucks.  The whole idea of the CA2104 is that you could get a hold of the pointer and use it to modify the contents of the object.  Using the 'Get' operation on an additional property doesn't fix the underlying problem, it simply fools the Code Analysis into accepting the pattern.  The proper way to handle this is to ignore the CA2104 in the properties of the project because it's a stupid warning to have in a world with public a DependencyProperty class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `protected readonly` field isn't really that clear.  As `protected`, you might expect that a derived class can initialize the field:

```
public class Test
{
    protected readonly ImmutableClass ImmutableMember;
}

public class SpecialTest : Test
{
    public SpecialTest() { ImmutableMember = new ImmutableClass; }
}
```

But, that's not the case--you will get a compile error (CS0191).

I don't know the exact impetus behind CA2104, but you can get the same result without readonly via:

```
public class Test
{
    protected ImmutableClass ImmutableMember {get; private set;}

    public Test()
        :this(new ImmutableClasse())
    {
    }

    public Test(ImmutableClass immutableClass)
    {
        ImmutableMember = new ImmutableClasse();
    }
}
```

and avoid the CA2104.

## Update:

w.r.t. to the comments (and to future readers), as you say you could use a backing field to get the read-only and provide a protected getter to get at it in derived classes:

```
public class Test
{
    private readonly ImmutableClass immutableMember;

    protected ImmutableClass ImmutableMember { get { return immutableMember; } }

    public Test(ImmutableClass immutableMember)
    {
        this.immutableMember = immutableMember;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm thinking that the way to go with this is somewhat similar. In fact, I'll make the `readonly` field private and expose it to the derived classes via a protected property. I'll mark this as the answer and add the code I finally used to my original question.